# How to set a Name for a line in my asp.net Chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I got this code i asp.net where I'm adding 4 series and pointers to display in my chart control. The problem is that they only comes as different color so I can't distinguish them. I've tried using the Legend and Tooltip property but it only sets the name on each data-point. What I'm looking for is just an explanation of the color in the button of the chart.

```
   private void runChartFunction(string fsql)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString()))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCom.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlCom.CommandText = fsql;

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);


        }

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var serie = chart.Series.Add(dt.Columns[i].ToString());
            serie.ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;


            string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];

            int row = 0;
            foreach (DataRow wk in dt.Rows)
            {
                x[row] = wk[0].ToString();
                y[row] = wk[i].ToInt();
                row++;
            }                
            serie.Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

        }
        chart.Visible = true;
}

<asp:Chart ID="chart" runat="server" Width="800">
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="chartArea">            
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by adding

```
<Legends>
    <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
</Legends>
```

in my ascx file and `chart.Legends[0].Enabled = true;` in my codebehind.